# NHibernate DataTypes - NoYes Boolean

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, types

What is the best way to get the reverse behavior of the YesNo Boolean type in NHibernate mapping?

I want 'Y' to mean false and 'N' to mean true.

Is there a NoYes type? Do you write a custom type? something really easy?

This issue of needing to reverse the Boolean exists on at least one field on over 40 tables.
Trying to adapt to a legacy database.

Comment: If "yes" means "no" then this must be the legacy database from Hell.

Comment: Just some weird conventions (about 7). And this is one of them. Not Hell, but maybe Purgatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that dealing with weird data formats in legacy databases can be achieved easily by implementing custom types. For example, I recently made a simple user type to map `DateTime` to 8 digit numbers on the form `yyyyMMdd`, which happened to be the way the dates were stored in a DB2 dump I had to use.

Los Techies have an example on implementing `IUserType` that you can use to solve your problem: [Mapping Strings to Booleans Using NHibernate's IUserType](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
The easier solution that I found was extend the CharBooelanType from NHibernate and use the new type on the mapping.
It would be like that:

```
using NHibernate.Type;
using NHibernate.SqlTypes;

namespace MyAssembly.MyNamespace 
{
    public class NewBoolType : CharBooleanType 
    {
        public NewBoolType()
            : base(new AnsiStringFixedLengthSqlType(1)) { }

        protected override string TrueString 
        {
            get { return "N"; }
        }

        protected override string FalseString 
        {
            get { return "Y"; }
        }

        public override string Name 
        {
            get { return "inverted_bool"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And the mapping would be like that:

```
<property name="MyProperty" column="MyColumn" type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.NewBoolType, MyAssembly" />
```